# Django - stop logout with javascript pop-up confirm box

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, popup

In my django site I have a logout button that redirects to the view `logout`. When the button is clicked it instantly logs the user out, but I would like a JS pop-up confirm box to appear then the logout button is clicked.

When the user clicks 'Ok' OR 'Cancel' it logs the user out. How can i prevent the `logout` view being called when the user clicks 'Cancel'?

*views.py*

```
def logout(request):
    if "user_info" in request.session:
        del request.session["user_info"]
    #redirect to login so the user can log back in
    return redirect("login")
```

*script.js*

```
function logout_popup() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        window.location.reload()
    }
}
```

*base.html*

```
<li onclick="logout_popup()" id="logout-tab"><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the `onclick` to the `a` tag:

```
<li id="logout-tab"><a onclick="logout_popup(event)" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
```

and the script:

```
function logout_popup(e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        window.location.reload()
    } else {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
}
```